# How to slide transition between two full width widgets?

Tags: flutter

I have a form with 2 steps, and I am hoping to animate the horizontal sliding to go between step 1 and 2.

here's a snippet from what I am trying so far following the docs (to be honest I am not sure I understand):

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  child: _formStep(context),
  transitionBuilder:
      (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
    final position = Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
        .animate(animation);

    return SlideTransition(
      position: position,
      child: child,
    );
  },
)
```

Step 1 to 2 transition will be right to left as Step 2 pulls in from the right.  Unfortunately, nothing seems to be happening so I know I am definitely missing something.

Can someone please point me into the right direction?  Its essentially the same transition as what you might expect to see on a carousel (horizontal transition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code. I'm using AnimatedPositioned since the steps (Containers) switch positions amongst them. I also assumed that the Steps (Containers) overlap each other.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Flutter Demo"),
        ),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Size size;
  double firstLeft, secondLeft;
  final double top = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        AnimtedSteps(
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              "Step 1",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ),
          top: top,
          left: firstLeft ?? 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        AnimtedSteps(
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              "Step 2",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ),
          top: top,
          left: secondLeft ?? size.width,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  if (firstLeft == 0 || firstLeft == null) {
                    firstLeft = -size.width;
                    secondLeft = 0;
                  } else {
                    firstLeft = 0;
                    secondLeft = size.width;
                  }
                },
              );
            },
            child: const Text("slide"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class AnimtedSteps extends StatelessWidget {
  final double top;
  final double left;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Widget child;

  const AnimtedSteps(
      {Key key, this.top, this.left, this.backgroundColor, this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      left: left,
      top: top,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 50,
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code a bit, eliminated the need for  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback;